# Add Chrome to dock with parameters via Automator with chrome icon

Tags: command-line, automator, dock

I need to have started Chrome without the build in Flash

via console you add the Parameters

--disable-internal-flash

which works fine, now i would like to have a Dock Icon which passes this parameter along

I have an Automator.app which encapsules the start up, but how du i get it somehow automatically to the dock.

Comment: Do you mean how do you get the Automator.app file onto the Dock outside of just dragging it into place?

Comment: jep i have a commandline skript additemtodock found on the net but it's not working always, so i am looking for something to get it into the dock

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Chess.app/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>"; killall Dock`.

Questions about adding applications with command line arguments to the Dock:

- [How can I force command-line arguments to a program shortcut in the dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/how-can-i-force-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-shortcut-in-the-dock)
- [How do I pass command line arguments to Dock items?](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items)
- [How to set launch options for programs on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/466917/how-to-set-launch-options-for-programs-on-os-x?lq=1)