# Adding options to application, upon startup?

Tags: startup, applications

I'd like to change how my Chrome starts up (specifically, i would like to add some options `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

How can i do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the option temporarily by quitting Chrome if it is already open and running either of these commands:

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

You can change the options permanently by replacing Chrome's executable with a shell script or by using another application or script for opening Chrome. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/how-can-i-force-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-shortcut-in-the-dock).