# Force Google Chrome use single process

Tags: macos, memory, google-chrome

Across the internet I found an interesting solution of how to make Chrome consume less memory and this is - forcing the application use single process for all the tabs. Unfortunately the instruction was made for Windows users. What should I do to try this feature in OS X? Will it actually help? And if not, what would you suggest to free more memory?

The corresponding article:
http://howto.excitebuzz.com/make-google-chrome-use-less-memory/120

Comment: The memory management on OS X is quite well executed. In my opinion you must give some reasons why you want to alter this. What is your system setup for example.

Comment: You could build your own version of Chrome that just does this using the Chromium project https://www.chromium.org/Home

Comment: You can pass the command-line argument `--single-process` to Chrome's executable. Take a look at the answers to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/how-can-i-force-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-shortcut-in-the-dock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running low on memory, you may try to use Safari instead, it allows you to enable single process mode.

For that you need to enable the Debug menu in Safari.

1. Open Terminal and type in the following command and hit <kbd>return</kbd>

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
   ```
2. Open the Safari app. (If you had Safari opened, you need to quit and open it again.)

   You will see a *Debug* menu, just check the *Disable Per-Tab Web Processes* item.

   [image: Safari hidden debug menu]
3. It will ask to quit Safari, click the button and open Safari again.
   *(It will close all tabs, so make sure you don't have anything pending)*
   [image: Restart safari dialog]
4. Open the Safari app again. You're in single process mode!
   You can check it by opening Activity Monitor app.

---

### Results

This is not very scientific, but just to give you some idea.

- #### Before (multi-process)

  > 50 Tabs opened on [apple.com](http://apple.com)
  >   Total system ram used **5.61GB**
  >
  > [image: 50 tabs opened on safari in multiprocess mode]
- #### After (single-process)

  > 50 Tabs opened on [apple.com](http://apple.com)
  >   Total system ram used **4.47GB**
  >
  > [image: 50 tabs opened on safari in multiprocess mode]

  Reduction in **1.14GB**

#### Reverting

- Just uncheck the `Debug > Disable Per-Tab Web Processes` to go back to the multi process mode.